# Parsing JSON in Delphi with slashes

Tags: json, parsing, delphi

I receive JSON strings from a WebService with slashes in it.

When I parse them, Delphi adds backslashes.

```pascal
V := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue( '{"Kode":"ABC/123" }') ;

V.ToString returns :  {"Kode":"ABC\\/123"}
```

What is best practice to parse JSON strings in Delphi?

And why does the function `V.Value` always returns an empty string?

In the unit `System.JSON`, I see the following code:

```pascal
function TJSONAncestor.Value: string;
begin
  Result := '';
end;
```

Do I need to add code myself to `System` units that ship with Delphi?

Comment: Why are you calling `ToString()` on the result of `ParseJSONValue()` anyway?

Comment: This is just an example to show how the JSON is parsed by Delphi. I recieve the JSON from a webservice and want to store it in a database.
So the webservice gives me kode= "ABC/123", and when I store the "toSTring" in my database, I have "ABC\/123" ... 
Just removing the backslash in the result does not work, because the value could also be "ABC\123" ...

Comment: @DirkJanssens did you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

`\` is *required* to be escaped as `\\`, so your claim that "*Just removing the backslash in the result does not work, because the value could also be `"ABC\123"`*" is wrong, as it would have to be `"ABC\\123"` instead.
The only other character *required* to be escaped is `"` as `\"`.  `/` is certainly not *required* to be escaped, but it MAY be escaped at the discretion of the implementation. It is not invalid to do so.  As to WHY `ToString()` does that, you would have to ask Embarcadero.

If you needed to, you could easily do a search-and-replace of `\/` into `/` without affecting other escape sequences, like `\\` and `\"`.  Or, try using [`ToJSON()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON.TJSONAncestor.ToJSON) instead of [`ToString()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON.TJSONAncestor.ToString).

Regarding `TJSONAncestor.Value()`, `TJSONAncestor` is a *base class*, and its `Value()` is a `virtual` method that returns a blank string *by default*.  Descendant classes ([`JSONString`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON.TJSONString), [`TJSONNumber`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON.TJSONNumber), etc) can *override* `Value()` to return more meaningful strings.  But in your example, your input string represents a JSON object, so `V` will be pointing at a `TJSONObject` instance, and `TJSONObject` does not override `Value()` because it does not make sense for an **object** to be represented by a **string**.  This is even documented behavior:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON.TJSONAncestor.Value

> Returns the string representation of a **simple** JSON element like a string, number or boolean.
>
> **For structured JSON elements like an object and array returns empty string.**

Comment: I believe Delphi's implementation comes from the list of supported two-characters sequence escape representations here https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7159#page-8.  `/` is in the list, but is indeed not required to be escaped. Characters 0x0000 to 0x001F are required to be though.